# I want to hide something and show the other after document is loaded

Tags: javascript

what's wrong with my code it gives me the following error 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var loading = document.getElementById('loading');       
function show(){
    loading.style.display = 'none';
    container.style.display = 'initial';
}
document.body.onload = show();
```

Comment: Where is the html part of your code? An element with the id 'container' or 'loading' is probably missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript executes from the top down on a page. There's two reasons this can fail, one is where 'container' and 'loading' ID's don't exist, and the other is where your function executes before the HTML is loaded.

If you put your snippet at the bottom of the page, after the HTML has loaded, it likely will work.

Also, a useful way to immediately execute a function is to do

```
(function() {
    //some code
})();
```

That way you don't have to use an extra line for `document.body.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way -

`var container = document.getElementById('container'); var loading = document.getElementById('loading');  document.body.onload = function(){ loading.style.display = 'none'; container.style.display = 'initial'; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
function show(){
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var loading = document.getElementById('loading'); 
    loading.style.display = 'none';
    container.style.display = 'initial';
}
document.body.onload = show();
```